# Mongodb schema structure - push and pop

Tags: javascript, python, json, mongodb

I'd like to have something like the following schema for a collection:

```
name1:
 - guid1 : [{ foo1}, {foo2}, .. {foo n}]
 - guid2 : [{ foo1}, {foo2}, .. {foo n}]
```

(1)
Each of the `foo` objects are dictionaries with the same internal structure - and so ideally i would have a single dictionary below `guid` where i could append additional data - but this does not seem to be possible (or is it?)

(2)
I'm struggling with being able to `pop` the data -i'm not sure how i can stucture a query to only `pop` a single `guid` off `name1`?

I'm using pymongo, if relevant.

Comment: what do you mean by 'pop'? if it's mongo's $pop then it's operation that removes first/last element of array and you have object (dictionary).

Comment: ive just realized that the $pop was working correctly (post some minor adjutments to my code), but i was expecting pop to return the value removed, which it doesnt, by design..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to throw a wrench your way, but have you looked into using [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/)? It sits on top of pymongo, and makes working with mongoDB a joy.  Check it out.

So your mongoengine declaration would look like this:

```
from mongoengine import *                           

class Foo(EmbeddedDocument):                  
    #Declare your Foo properties here

class Guid(EmbeddedDocument):                  
    name = StringField()                 
    foos = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Foo))                                    

class Name(Document):                          
    title = StringField(required=True)                                       
    guids = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Guid))
```

Then you can grab your Name and loop through its properties as nice object, remove and pop the Guids, then type Name.save()

Comment: i think ill have to fundamentally change how i structure the data - thanks this looks v intersting

Comment: Yeah, i took a stab at it based on you question. Let me know if you need any more help with it.

Comment: If foo1 is the same object in guid1 and guid2,  then change the Foo to implement Document, and change the foos line to: foos = ListField(ReferenceField(Foo))